# Textview animation works only once on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

There is a button and when it is clicked on I want a message to slide to right and then fade away. It works only the first time this certain layout is loaded. This is what I've written

```
popTextView.animate().translationX(popTextView.getWidth()).alpha(0.0f).setDuration(1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set repeat rount for your animation.

```
  animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

or

```
animation.setRepeatCount(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling `YourView.getAnimation().start();` while clicking on button